# Embed .pdf file into latex-document goes wrong

Tags: pdf

I have the following problem:

```
 ....
(here some text1)
(here should the .pdf file appear)
(here some text2)
....
```

I need that order which you can see above. But the situation is that .pdf file appears after text2. I have written the following:

```
 This is an example line for text1.

    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Figure1.pdf}
    \caption{example}
    \label{Fig1}
\end{figure}

This is an example for the text2 part.
```

What I have forgotten?

best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTeX tries to find the best position for the figure in the document.
If you are not happy with the result.
Add `\usepackage{float}` to your preamble and use `[H]` instead of `[ht]` as the figure positioning option.

`[H]` means: exactly HERE, do not float